# How to call a class object to be executed by the tkinter button in developing a knowledge based system using pyknow

Tags: class, button, tkinter, pycharm

Am currently doing a basic knowledge based system using the pyknow library and I would like to create a user interface for it; which I have done so well using tkinter. The only problem is trying to get **the class method to be called** by the button so as to fetch the results from the entry field and insert them into the listbox:

Here below is the section of code i have tried to implement with the GUI running very well:

Here below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from random import choice
from pyknow import *







class Kbsgui:


    def __init__(self, window):
        self.l1 = Label(window, text="1. What is the self assessment status for that particular year? (0 - missing, 1 - present) ")
        self.l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.l2 = Label(window, text="2. Are there self assessments existing betwwen 1992 - 2014? (yes/no) ")
        self.l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.l3 = Label(window, text="3. Are there Credit balances for successive years? (yes/no) ")
        self.l3.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.l4 = Label(window, text="4. Are there debit balances for successive years? (yes/no) ")
        self.l4.grid(row=3, column=0)

        # define entries
        self.self_ass_status = tk.Entry()
        self.e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=self.self_ass_status)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.self_ass_captured = tk.Entry()
        self.e2 = Entry(window, textvariable=self.self_ass_captured)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.credit_bal_status = tk.Entry()
        self.e3 = Entry(window, textvariable=self.credit_bal_status)
        self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.debit_bal_status = tk.Entry()
        self.e4 = Entry(window, textvariable=self.debit_bal_status)
        self.e4.grid(row=3, column=1)


#create window object
window = Tk()

window.title("RPA-KBS APP")

kg = Kbsgui(window)

#-----Beginning of KBS Class----

class Ledger_errors(Fact):

    pass


class LedgerErrorsInferenceEngine(KnowledgeEngine):

    def returns_missing(self):
        print('\n The returns for the year(s) is uncaptured. ')

    @Rule(AND(Ledger_errors(self_assessment_status='0'),
              Ledger_errors(self_assessments_captured='yes')
              )
          )
    def credit_balances(self):
        print('\n Uncaptured losses for preceding years. ')
        print('\n')

    @Rule(AND(Ledger_errors(debit_balances_status='yes'),
              Ledger_errors(self_assessments_captured='yes')
              )
          )
    def erroneous_balances(self):
        print(' \n credits not carried forward to successive years. ')
        print('\n')

    @Rule(AND(Ledger_errors(credit_balances_status='yes'),
              Ledger_errors(self_assessments_captured='yes')
              )
          )

    def undefined_errors(self):
        print('\n')


def display_results():
    for i in range(1):
           print('\n')

try:
    self_assessment_status = int(kg.self_ass_status.get())
    self_assessments_captured = str(kg.self_ass_captured.get())
    credit_balances_status = str(kg.credit_bal_status.get())
    debit_balances_status = str(kg.debit_bal_status.get())
    engine = LedgerErrorsInferenceEngine()
    engine.reset()
    engine.declare(Ledger_errors(self_assessment_status=choice([self_assessment_status]),self_assessments_captured=choice([self_assessments_captured]),
                                          credit_balances_status=choice([credit_balances_status]), debit_balances_status=choice([debit_balances_status])))
    engine.run()

except ValueError:
    pass

#-----End of KBS Class----
    def __call__(self):
        le = LedgerErrorsInferenceEngine(KnowledgeEngine)

    # define listbox
    list1 = Listbox(window, height=6, width=90)
    list1.grid(row=4, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=2)

    # Attach scrollbar to the list
    sb1 = Scrollbar(window)
    sb1.grid(row=4, column=2, rowspan=6)

    list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
    sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

    list1.insert(tk.END, display_results())

    # Define buttons
    b1 = Button(window, text="View Results", width=12, bg="red",command=lambda: Ledger_errors.display_results())
    b1.grid(row=3, column=3)




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that is not needed in order to reproduce the problem you're having.